# How can I achieve fault tolerance with LDAP Server

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, disaster-recovery

I am using UnboundID LDAP SDK for designing a LDAP Client. I am thinking of fault tolerance schema with this API. I need to add LDAP secondary server with the primary server and if there is a failure in primary server the service should move to secondary server. The service should continue without any interruption. How can I achieve this with UnboundID LDAP SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the FailoverServerSet (https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/FailoverServerSet.html) documentation of the UnboundID LDAP SDK. It provides an example how you can achieve what you are looking for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, this is the way of doing this. Thank you for the answer.